# Getting value after selecting dropdown list in the clone format

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, clone, codeigniter-2

Selecting the tax type dropdown ,the tax - type value will be posted and getting value into the 'data'.The value should be passed to text field which is next to tax - type.
The whole functionality is in clone format.

```
$('.tax_type').change(function()
{
     var tax_type=$(this).val();
         targeturl=path+"orders/get_rate/"+tax_type;
         $.ajax({ url: targeturl, success: function(data)
         {
         alert(data);
         $(this).parent().next().find("input").val(data);
        }

});

});
```

Comment: what is the error ?????

Comment: Am getting the value from my sql,but it is not showing value in text field near to the drop down i.e tax-type.i want to show the value in tax -rate field.But it is in multiple clone format.If effecting whole clone text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
    $(function(){
        $('.tax_type').change(function(){
            var $this = this;
            var tax_type = $this.value;
            var targeturl=path+"orders/get_rate/"+tax_type;
            $.ajax({ url: targeturl, success: function(data){
                 $($this).parent().next().find("input").val(data);
                }
            });
        });
    })
```